# On clicking the row of a grid, checkboxes of other rows getting unchecked using checkboxselectionmodel in GWT

Tags: checkbox, grid, gxt

I have a multiSelectCombobox that uses a grid with checkboxselectionModel. I want checkboxes getting checked on clicking the checkbox, but what is happening here is when i click the row of an unchecked checkbox, that checkbox gets selected while all the other checkboxes that were previously checked get unchecked automatically.

I have seen many threads posted on Sencha but none seem to be of any help.

```
 grid=new Grid(skillsetStore, new ColumnModel(columnConfigs));
        cm.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
        grid.setStyleAttribute("borderTop", "none");
        grid.setBorders(true);
        grid.setStripeRows(true);
        grid.setWidth(300);
        grid.getView().setForceFit(true);
        grid.getView().setAutoFill(true);
        grid.setSelectionModel(cm);
        grid.addPlugin(cm);
        grid.setHideHeaders(true);
```

This is my grid that i am using...

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was setting the checkbox value to false in data bind complete event. Once I removed it, it worked fine